# How can I configure my Amazon EC2 instance to be accessible via RDP only through a VPN?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp, aws-vpn

I want that my EC2 instance is accessible via the Remote Desktop connection from my Windows host only through the AWS VPN Client I created.

My EC2 instance follows a security group that contains many rules and one of them is an inbound rule that allows the traffic via RDP (port 3389) only for the range of addresses assigned from the VPN. But it still doesn't work for me if I connect to the VPN Client and I get an address in this range. Can anyone help me solving this problem please?

Comment: When you connect to the EC2 instance, how are you referencing the instance? For example, are you using a DNS name or an IP address? You would need to access the instance via a **private IP address** -- can you show us that this is what you are using?

Comment: I reference with the IP address, usually with the public one when I was accessing the instance without any VPN. Now I tried with the VPN on and using the private IP address to RDP it but nothing changes.

Comment: Are you saying that you are attempting to RDP into the EC2 instance via the VPN using the **private IP address** of the instance, but it fails to connect? What do you mean by "doesn't work for me" -- is there an error, or a timeout? If you _temporarily_ open the Security Group to accept RDP on `0.0.0.0/0`, and connect to the private IP address of the EC2 instance, does it work?

Comment: No, by changing the rule to accept any address, I can only RDP with the public IP. The error is in both situations:
Remote Desktop cannot connect to the remote computer for one of the following reasons:

1) Remote access to the server is not enabled.
2) The remote computer is turned off.
3) The remote computer is not available on the network.

Verify that the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network and that remote access is enabled.

Comment: Are you able to connect to it using a **private IP address** when the VPN connection is active (and the security group temporarily fully open)?

Comment: Not even, I can't RDP using the private address never. RDP to my instance only works using the public IP without using the VPN and with RDP entry rule in the security group set to any address. Could this be a problem? How can it be solved?